# Creating and Dropping a BQ temp table in same execution of airflow and then in next run while the table is created first but table drop is not working

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, airflow

Creating and Dropping a BQ temp table in same execution of airflow and then in next run while the table is created first but table is not identifiable for drop.

1st execution:

Create_BQ temp table and then drop the table. DAG is running fine.

2nd execution:

Initially table was not available as dropped in previous execution. In this execution; table was created first and before dropping while checking if table_name == 'temp_table_name';it returns false and table drop not executing.

Comment: If you find my answer helpful for your question, please consider to accept/upvote it as per [stackoverflow guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are facing can be because DAG has been scheduled from a back date. In that case, Airflow does not give the specified scheduled_interval between the consecutive DAG runs. It appears that this is allowing very less time for the table metadata to be updated in BigQuery. So, I have set the parameter **retries** as 1 and  **retry_delay** as 2 minutes i.e. the delete task will be retried after a wait of 2 minutes, if it fails. Also, in your case the table is being created with the same name each time and it may result in task failures for concurrent running DAGs, hence I have set **depends_on_past** as True so that the tasks for subsequent DAGs run only when the previous DAG run succeeded.

You can refer to the below code for the same.

**code 1:**

```
import os
import time
import datetime
from urllib.parse import urlparse

from airflow import models
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.bigquery import (

    BigQueryCreateEmptyTableOperator,
    BigQueryDeleteTableOperator
)
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago

PROJECT_ID = "my-project"
BQ_LOCATION = "us-east1"
YESTERDAY = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)

default_dag_args = {

    'start_date': YESTERDAY,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': datetime.timedelta(minutes=2),
    'depends_on_past':True,
    }

with models.DAG(
    "DAG9",
    schedule_interval=datetime.timedelta(minutes=5),
    default_args=default_dag_args ) as dag:
    
    # [START howto_operator_bigquery_create_table]
    create_table = BigQueryCreateEmptyTableOperator(
        task_id="create_table",
        dataset_id="demo14",
        table_id="tab",
        schema_fields=[
            {"name": "emp_name", "type": "STRING", "mode": "REQUIRED"},
            {"name": "salary", "type": "INTEGER", "mode": "NULLABLE"},
        ],
    )

    delete_table = BigQueryDeleteTableOperator(
    task_id="delete_table",
    deletion_dataset_table="my-project.demo14.tab",

    )

    create_table >> delete_table
```

When I scheduled to run the DAG from the current date I did not face any inconsistency. You can refer to the below code.

**Code 2 :**

```
import os
import time
import datetime
from urllib.parse import urlparse

from airflow import models
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.bigquery import (

    BigQueryCreateEmptyTableOperator,
    BigQueryDeleteTableOperator
)
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago

PROJECT_ID = "my-project"
BQ_LOCATION = "us-east1"


with models.DAG(
    "DAG5",
    schedule_interval=datetime.timedelta(minutes=5),  # Override to match your needs
    start_date=datetime.datetime(2021,11,14,7,30),
    tags=["example"],
) as dag:
    # [START howto_operator_bigquery_create_table]
    create_table = BigQueryCreateEmptyTableOperator(
        task_id="create_table",
        dataset_id="demo12",
        table_id="tab",
        schema_fields=[
            {"name": "emp_name", "type": "STRING", "mode": "REQUIRED"},
            {"name": "salary", "type": "INTEGER", "mode": "NULLABLE"},
        ],
    )

    delete_table = BigQueryDeleteTableOperator(
    task_id="delete_table",
    deletion_dataset_table="my-project.demo12.tab",

    )

    create_table >> delete_table
```